# Laravel8: How to update multiple records in controller function?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables:

```
| Invoices  | Colete         |
| --------  | -------------- |
| ID        | ID             |
|tagacars_id| car_id         | 
|client_id  | clients_id     |
|           | invoice_id     |
```

My query fetches all the coletes whose car_id and clients_id are the same as invoices tagacars_id and client_id and also only those coletes that don't have an invoice_id (yet)

This is my controller function for that:

```
$datacolete = DB::table('invoices')
    
    ->join('coletes',function($join){
        $join->on('invoices.client_id','=','coletes.clients_id')
        ->on('coletes.tagacars_id','=','invoices.car_id')
        ->whereNull('coletes.invoice_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Now. I would want those coletes that do not have an invoice_id at the moment they are linked to the next created invoice to fetch it's id (so invoice.id = colete.invoice_id)

I've tried this:

```
$coleteid = $id;
    foreach($datacolete as $datacolete){
        $datacolete = Invoice::find($id);
        $datacolete->invoice_id = $request->$id;
        $datacolete->save();
    }
```

But it only returns me an error. `Call to undefined method stdClass::save()`

I have below my whole controller function so you can see:

```
public function showinvoiceview(Request $request, $id){
    $invoices=invoice::findOrFail($id);

$datacolete = DB::table('invoices')
    
    ->join('coletes',function($join){
        $join->on('invoices.client_id','=','coletes.clients_id')
        ->on('coletes.tagacars_id','=','invoices.car_id')
        ->whereNull('coletes.invoice_id');
    })
    ->get();
$coleteid = $id;
    foreach($datacolete as $datacolete){
        $datacolete = Invoice::find($id);
        $datacolete->invoice_id = $request->$id;
        $datacolete->save();
    }
   return view('admin.invoice-view',compact('invoices','data','datacolete'));
   
 }
```

Any idea if this is at least possible to do? Do you have any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: In the loop you are looking for same record `Invoice::find($id)` till the end of the loop, is this strange?? `$datacolete = Invoice::find($id);` did you debug what is coming in `$datacolete` variable

Comment: `foreach($datacolete as $datacolete){` Why does the [*iterable_expression*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and *value* have the **same** name?

Comment: Secondly, `$datacolete->invoice_id = $request->$id;` I think you meant to write `$request->id` instead.